# Async set to True throws error, but still sends data to server side

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asynchronous

When setting Async to false, this code is processed fine, but when setting Aync to true, as soon as the call to Ajax is made, it throws error (alert msg with "fail") BUT it is still processed (meaning data is sent to server side and the data is saved!).

So setting Async to false or true does the job, but setting Async to true will go to Error and throw error.

I am calling this Ajax through an onClick event on a button.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    url: "ScriptWS.asmx/UpdateXml",
    data: "{'QuestionKey':'" + QuestionKey + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        UpdateXml_CallBack(data);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert('fail');
});
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: asyc: true is never the answer. You can modal out the screen if you don't want user interaction. But browsers don't like async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer.

The problem was that I was running a for-loop to send AJAX calls. So it was sending AJAX calls simultaneously, and the responses were getting lost, or interrupted by the next AJAX call.

I solved this problem by using AjaxQueue from here
http://gnarf.net/2011/06/21/jquery-ajaxqueue/

Thank you.